# Reading yenc encoded data into java

Tags: java, text, encoding, character-encoding, inputstream

I have this text file that i encoded with an yenc encoder and i intended to decode it with a java yenc decoder. The yenc decoder isn't the problem.

I read the encoded file in and then print the lines on the console:
But characters get mispresented:

THIS
`q˜œ‹–74˜“›ŸJsnJJJJ` 
TURNS INTO `q?˜?œ‹–74˜“›Ÿ?JsnJJJJ`

Not only when I print it on the console, but also when writing it to a file.

So the decoded file will not be the encoded file in the beginning.
How can i solve this?

I really have no idea.
I tried replacing the "?" but that didn't have any effect.

Comment: Are you also viewing the contents of the file in the console?  It sounds to me like the problem is that the console does not support extended ascii,

Comment: Yes, but the problem still persist even if I write them to a new file. So the inputstream or the outputstream changes the data somehow.

Comment: What happens if you view the contents of the new file you write to with a text editor other than a console application?